# symfony close iframe when form is submitted

Tags: symfony, iframe

I have an iframe which is rendering a form. I got everything to work as i wanted but now i want to dismiss the iframe that is rendering the form when it is being submitted.

this is the controller:

```
public function createIssueAction(Request $request, $messageUid)
    {

         $form = $this->createForm(

          new IssuePopupFormType($this->container),

          $message
        );
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $message = $form->getData();

              //Doing some work

                $this->get('session')
                  ->getFlashBag()
                  ->add(
                    'success',
                    'issue' . $message . ' is created'
                  );

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_mail_inbox'));
            }
        }

        return $this->render(
          'AcmeBundle:Issue:issuePopup.html.twig',
          [
            'message' => $message,
            'form' => $form->createView()
          ]
        );
    }
```

How can i dismiss the iframe when the form is submitted instead of a url-redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definetly only remove/close the iframe from the embedding document as it is inside its code.

So you can do this with [cross-document-messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage)

or you use a wrapper, like easyxdm

this may also be helpful http://cross-browser.com/talk/inter-frame_comm.html

whatever, instead of redirecting

```
 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_mail_inbox'));
```

you render a view that executes some javascript that posts some status message

on the embedding document you listen for that message and if you receive it you dismiss/hide/remove the iframe

well it depends on your design but maybe there are lots of much simpler solutions, for example in your symfony action you render an empty html-view
and your iframe´s css has height:auto so if it also has no borders and nothing it looks like its dismissed